Google API Authorisation
I am using some of the basic google API python scripts about accessing drive and creating files etc...
These exact same files worked some months ago, but now I get errors when the tokens are trying to be refreshed. It also does not prompt me to log in.
The setup code is as follows:
def create_service(credentials, api_name, api_version, *scopes):
    print("-"*100)
    print("Data: ", credentials, api_name, api_version, scopes, sep='-')
    CREDENTIALS = credentials
    API_SERVICE_NAME = api_name
    API_VERSION = api_version
    SCOPES = [scope for scope in scopes[0]]
    print("Scopes: ", SCOPES)
    
    token_file = f'token_{API_SERVICE_NAME}_{API_VERSION}.json'
    
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists(token_file):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(token_file, SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                CREDENTIALS, SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open(token_file, 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=creds)
        print('Service created successfully')
        print("-"*100)
        return service
    except HttpError as error:
        # Handle errors from drive API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
    except Exception as error:
        print('Unable to connect.')
        print(error)
        return None

The output error is:
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Bad Request', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Bad Request'})


I am not sure what to try, this is a personalish project so I am not sure if I should make the project "In production".
Does anyone have any ideas? I have tried re-making the credentials json file and it is still not working.

Did you try deleting the token file.  But put the project in production first
